# geoJSON property "undefined" in popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am working on a Leaflet map. So far, things are going fairly well. However, I am having a problem getting one piece of information into my popup.

The popup should display the name of the canyon associated with the marker, along with the name of the state that the canyon is in. The state abbreviation is displaying, but the canyon name is not. I get "Undefined" where I should see a canyon's name in every popup.

Here is the feature creation function. The popup is in the first part:

```
function createFeatures2(canyonsURL, stylecallback, layer) {
    // Define a function we want to run once for each feature in the features array
    // Give each feature a popup with name and state of canyon
    function onEachFeature2(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Canyon +
            "<hr><p>" + feature.properties.State);
    }

    // Create a GeoJSON layer containing the features array on the data objects
    // Run the onEachFeature function once for each piece of data in the array
    var canyon = d3.json(canyonsURL, {
        pointToLayer: function(_geometry, coordinates) {
            return L.circleMarker(coordinates);
        },
        onEachFeature2: onEachFeature2,
        style2: style2
    }).addTo(layer);

}
```

Again, the markers are displaying just right.

Here is a sample from the geoJSON data. Please excuse the spacing:

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
-103.4423,
37.132
]
},
"properties": {
"Canyon": "Aguaje Canyon",
"State": "Colorado"
}
},
```

Any ideas about why this would successfully get the "State" but not the "Canyon"? I used an online converter to convert a csv to a geoJSON, but I don't think that's the problem--it worked with a different csv file.

Comment: Before you call `bindPopup`, do a `console.log(feature)` -- make sure that the `properties.Canyon` field exists on the output.

Comment: Thank you for the tip; it's not printing to the console at all. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I just got it. (I must be tired... I totally put it in the wrong place.) The d3 is pulling in the features correctly and completely. It's got to be something up with the function. I have a createFeatures that uses different data (and returns another geological feature). It's working fine. The only thing that I changed was the name of what I want returned (canyons instead of the other geological feature).